# $SESSION not working despite numerous tries and search online

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am coding an online quizzer using PHP. Whenever the answerer of the quiz choose the correct answer, the code will automatically +1 to his overall score.

To do that, I used `$_SESSION['score']=0;` to first set the score to zero and `$_SESSION['score']++;` whenever the answerer gets the answer correct for each question.

However, I have no idea why the score is not adding up despite the answerers answering the questions correctly.

When the answerer answers the question correctly, the score is still 0 for some reason and I have no idea why. May I know what went wrong? Thank you.

Things I have tried:

1.Changing `$_SESSION['score']++;` to `$_SESSION['score']+1;`

2.Changing:

`if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
    $_SESSION['score']=0;
    }`

to just

`$_SESSION['score']=0;`

3.Changing

`if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
    $_SESSION['score']++;
    }`

to just:

`if($correct_choice = $selected_choice){
    $_SESSION['score']++;
    }`

Below is the code for process.php:

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

 if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])){
    $_SESSION['score']=0;

}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $number=$_POST['number'];
    $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $next=$number+1;

   /*
    *   Get total questions
    */
    $query="SELECT* FROM questions";
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $total=$results->num_rows;

   /*
    *   Get correct choice
    */
    $query = "SELECT* FROM `choices` WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct=1";
    //Get result
    $results= mysqli_query($con,$query);

    //Get row
    $row=$results->fetch_assoc();

    //Set Correct choices
    $correct_choice=$row['id'];

    //Compare choice made with correct choice
    if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        $_SESSION['score']++;
    }


    //Check if last question
    if($number == $total){
        header("Location: final.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("Location: question.php?n=".$next);
    }

}
```

Just tried something:

```
if($correct_choice == $selected_choice){
        echo "same";
    } else{
        echo "not same";
    }
```

Even though `$correct_choice` and `$selected_choice` are both equals to 1, the code still returns as "not same"?

Comment: Did you maybe try using $_SESSION['score'] = $_SESSION['score'] + 1 ?

Comment: Wonder, do you see warning `Headers already sent`?

Comment: I would go for a non global variable to store the value and update $_SESSION only when you need to pass the value to another page

Comment: Did you check your browser cookie store for an existing `PHPSESSID` or something=

Comment: are you sure ($correct_choice == $selected_choice) is satisfying , did you checked with with echo ?

Comment: @sandeepKumar, yes I am tried it with ech and ($correct_choice == $selected_choice) is satisfying  @u_mulder i did not see `Headers already sent1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening and closing a lot of PHP tags - unnecessarily. If you have error reporting on, and being displayed on screen, it would likely be saying 'headers already sent'. That, is likely the issue.

Since the process.php file is all php - just open the `<?php` tag once - and don't even bother to close it at the end - unless you are explicitly outputting something (which is bad practice anyway for a larger program, better to use a small framework, and separate templates).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code does not output anything to the browser before session_start() is called.

you can find more information about  $_SESSION superglobal [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.